# Until loop keeps runing even when the phrase is true?

Tags: ruby, loops

I have the following code:

```
until (@world.exists? decision || decision == '')
  UiHandler.print_error(UiHandler::NO_TILE)
  UiHandler.print_turn_message
  decision = gets.chomp
end
```

which should allow the player to skip a turn by entering an empty line. But for some reason the until loop keeps running even when the condition is true

i.e. passing in '1 1' does work and stop the loop, since it exists in world, but passing nothing doesn't, even though puts (@world.exists? decision || decision == '') gives 'true'

What would cause an until loop not to stop even when the condition is met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix is

```
(@world.exists?(decision) || decision == '')
```

Otherwise - `@world.exists? decision || decision == ''` is being treated as `@world.exists?(decision || decision == '')`, which is not correct expression, you intended to write.

As `decision` is a *string object*, which in Ruby is considered as *truth* value, `decision || decision == ''` (in the code written by you) will be evaluated as `true` too. This `decision` will be passed as a method argument to the method `@world.exists?` always.